# 'gem install nokogiri' fails in `bundle install` [Mac OS X Lion]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

System: Mac OS X Lion

running `bundle install` tells me to do:
`gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.2'`

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
1ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/ernsheong/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
extconf.rb:10: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... yes
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in -lxslt... yes
checking for exsltFuncRegister() in -lexslt... yes
checking for xmlHasFeature()... yes
checking for xmlFirstElementChild()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling html_document.c
compiling html_element_description.c
compiling html_entity_lookup.c
compiling html_sax_parser_context.c
compiling html_sax_push_parser.c
compiling nokogiri.c
compiling xml_attr.c
compiling xml_attribute_decl.c
compiling xml_cdata.c
compiling xml_comment.c
compiling xml_document.c
compiling xml_document_fragment.c
compiling xml_dtd.c
compiling xml_element_content.c
compiling xml_element_decl.c
compiling xml_encoding_handler.c
compiling xml_entity_decl.c
compiling xml_entity_reference.c
compiling xml_io.c
xml_io.c:28:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  return safe_len;
  ~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
compiling xml_libxml2_hacks.c
compiling xml_namespace.c
compiling xml_node.c
compiling xml_node_set.c
compiling xml_processing_instruction.c
compiling xml_reader.c
compiling xml_relax_ng.c
compiling xml_sax_parser.c
compiling xml_sax_parser_context.c
compiling xml_sax_push_parser.c
compiling xml_schema.c
compiling xml_syntax_error.c
compiling xml_text.c
compiling xml_xpath_context.c
xml_xpath_context.c:189:30: warning: format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure) [-Wformat-security]
  rb_raise(rb_eRuntimeError, message);
                             ^~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
compiling xslt_stylesheet.c
linking shared-object nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/lib'

make install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 nokogiri.bundle /Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2/lib/nokogiri
make: /usr/bin/install: No such file or directory
make: *** [/Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

It is somewhat similar but still different from [OS X Lion, Attempting Nokogiri install - libxml2 is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134423/os-x-lion-attempting-nokogiri-install-libxml2-is-missing) and [An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.5.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725679/installing-nokogiri-1-5-2)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you're missing `/usr/bin/install`; do you have Xcode installed? (I assume you do, as everything compiled. Not sure why else you'd be missing that...)

Comment: i solved the problem by reinstalling ruby using the following Gist: https://gist.github.com/1856859 a friend pointed out that the --with-gcc=clang option during install is important for Lion/Snow Leopard

Comment: Go ahead and provide an answer for your own question. It may help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem by reinstalling ruby using the following Gist: [gist.github.com/1856859](http://gist.github.com/1856859). A friend pointed out that the --with-gcc=clang option during install is important for Lion/Snow Leopard

Answer (score 0):

There is a minor issue in configre.in of stock ruby-1.9.3-p125. You may try using latest head of RVM as mentioned in "[Issue updating Ruby on Mac with Xcode 4.3.1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651670/issue-updating-ruby-on-mac-with-xcode-4-3-1/9651747#9651747)

Other module may fail due to dynamic linking.